# Merge two encoding without lambda layer in order to convert Keras model wiith tfjs

Tags: keras, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I'm looking for creating a siamese network with Keras and I found [this article on Medium](https://towardsdatascience.com/one-shot-learning-with-siamese-networks-using-keras-17f34e75bb3d) that unfortunately uses a Lambda layer in order to compute the absolute difference between the two output encodings of the convolutional network. The problem is that I cannot use Lambda Layers in my network because I want then convert the final Keras model to a tfjs model and according to Tensorflowjs, these type of layers cannot be converted.

**My question is**: is possible to use a Merge Layer to obtain the same result or another Keras layer that is compatible with tensorlfowjs? If yes, could you show me an example because I'm new to Keras.
I looked around for other Siamese implementation but all use this Lambda Layer.

```
# Define the tensors for the two input images
left_input = Input(input_shape)
right_input = Input(input_shape)

# Convolutional Neural Network
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, (10,10), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape,
               kernel_initializer=initialize_weights, kernel_regularizer=l2(2e-4)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Conv2D(128, (7,7), activation='relu',
                 kernel_initializer=initialize_weights,
                 bias_initializer=initialize_bias, kernel_regularizer=l2(2e-4)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Conv2D(128, (4,4), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initialize_weights,
                 bias_initializer=initialize_bias, kernel_regularizer=l2(2e-4)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Conv2D(256, (4,4), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initialize_weights,
                 bias_initializer=initialize_bias, kernel_regularizer=l2(2e-4)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(4096, activation='sigmoid',
               kernel_regularizer=l2(1e-3),
               kernel_initializer=initialize_weights,bias_initializer=initialize_bias))

# Generate the encodings (feature vectors) for the two images
encoded_l = model(left_input)
encoded_r = model(right_input)

# Add a customized layer to compute the absolute difference between the encodings
L1_layer = Lambda(lambda tensors:K.abs(tensors[0] - tensors[1]))
L1_distance = L1_layer([encoded_l, encoded_r])

# Add a dense layer with a sigmoid unit to generate the similarity score
prediction = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid',bias_initializer=initialize_bias)(L1_distance)

# Connect the inputs with the outputs
siamese_net = Model(inputs=[left_input,right_input],outputs=prediction)
```

Answer (score 3):

A custom Lambda layer can be created and registered.

Here is a subset of the `siamese_net` (just to demonstrate the use of the lambda layer)

```
left_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(32,)) 
right_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(32,))  

L1_layer = Lambda(lambda tensors:tf.abs(tensors[0] - tensors[1]))
L1_distance = L1_layer([left_input, right_input])

prediction = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(L1_distance)

model = Model(inputs=[left_input,right_input],outputs=prediction)
```

Save the model

```
model.save('my_model.h5')
```

Convert the model to js

```
tensorflowjs_converter \
    --input_format=keras \
    my_model.h5 \
    tfjs
```

Use the model in javascript

```
class Lambda extends tf.layers.Layer {
    constructor() {
      super({})
    }

    static get className() {
      return 'Lambda';
    }

    computeOutputShape(inputShape) {
      return [inputShape[0]];
    }

    call(inputs, kwargs) {
      this.invokeCallHook(inputs, kwargs);
      return tf.abs(inputs[0].sub(inputs[1]))
    }
  }

  tf.serialization.SerializationMap.register(Lambda);
```

Here is a [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1iE1fNex2heBjJoCX_04ZyZqcDD5fCl1Q)